# Import database from mysql server 5.0

Tags: mysql

I have created one database in mysql server 5.0.How i can import this database(I have created the database using mysql command Line)

Comment: What do you want to import it into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql -ppasword -uuserxy database < database_dump.sql
```

Comment: make sure you use the right user and password, for database you need to have an empty database already created in your mysql (fill in the right database name here), additionally the dumfile needs to be spelled right (take the filename you got from your dump)

Comment: Is their any way to export database to a dump file

Comment: yes, on commandline do: 'mysqldump -ppasword -uuserxy databasename_to_export > database_dump.sql'